# Get number of tablerow inside of tablebody with PHP

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to find the number of `<tr>` inside of `<tbody>` using PHP?
I do not want to use JQuery/Javascript.

```
<tbody id="tblBody">
    <tr>one</tr>
    <tr>two</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Use a DOM parser library.

Comment: Like @Barmar said. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: Not entirely reliable, but if you have the html markup in a string and it's well formed, you can use `substr_count` to count the ocurrences of a substring. Like `$count = substr_count($html, '<tr');`